# TFS Build 2010 + Referencing DLLs from drops

Tags: tfsbuild

I'm looking for some help / ideas on how to solve this issue. I have a solution of common code that is built using TFS (Service online version) Build (VS2010) and builds whenever the common code is modified. I would have a drop structure such as:

Drop Folder_Version 1.0.0.0
Drop Folder_Version 1.0.0.1
Drop Folder_Version 1.0.0.2

Where the last digit keeps incrementing everytime a change is made to common code.
Then, I have client specific code that references some of my common DLLs. I want to automate the build of this code in TFS Build but not sure how to go about this.
1) I thought of creating a master solution that contains both the common code project and client specific project but this would not create a variance in how my common code gets versioned (I'm using TFS to increment the common code whenever my common code TFS Build occurs).
2) I thought of adding a reference path to the common code from TFS Drop folder but since the folder is always sequentially incremented, someone would need to manually update this reference path everytime the client specific code builds.

I was thinking of maybe creating a copy of every common code drop to a general drop folder that way the path would be static but do not know how to do that. Or if someone else has a good idea...

Note this is using Team Foundation SERVICE, so it is all online...

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the following link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a00f0808-d2cb-465c-a908-e4673d6a2d55/copying-files-to-a-static-drop-directory-tfs-hosted-build-service

This is the solution I ended up implementing.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know enough about the team foundation service but I hope you have access to the build defintion and you will be able to customize it. Make your client specific code look for the DLL's from a root BIN folder.

Then within the build definition, after the "GetWorkspace" activity. Add a new activity (from the toobox either CopyDirectory or InvokeProcess) to copy all the built DLL's from your droplocation to the root bin folder. To identify the latest version, you can create a custom activity (write c# code), which will look at the drop folder and identify the greatest version number. After finding the version number set it to a variable, which will be then used by the CopyDirectory or InvokeProcess activity.

CopyDirectory is straight forward, you just add the source and destination location and you are good to go. For InvokeProcess you can enter the "FileName = xcopy.exe" and fill in the correct arguments.

Makes sense?

Comment: Yes, I've been playing around with CopyDirectory, I think this would do what I wanted...EXCEPT it doesn't seem to overwrite the file if it already exists in the root bin folder.

I was thinking I could copy the entire drop location to the root folder all the time. But I'm seeing issues that the files are not being overwritten - this is using CopyDirectory.

Is there some special action / command / ?? in order to overwrite existing files?

Comment: I didnt know about that till now. You can use the InvokeProcess activity, use the "FileName=xcopy.exe" and pass the particular arguments. xcopy /y will overwrite existing folder/files without prompting. 

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I've tried InvokeProcess doing:
xcopy C:\a\Binaries\myfile.dll $/Dev/TestFolder /Y /R

I see a record in the build log but no file gets copied to $/Dev/TestFolder.

Might be a quirk of the hosted server technology...or there's a small typo in my command line ... or..???

Comment: Yes, I need to copy the files from the Build to an additional location on the server. The first one goes to Drops/IterationX while the copy goes to Drops/Latest. Not sure how SourcesDirectory would help...

Remember this is Team Foundation Hosted Service so it's all online.

Comment: "are you trying to copy the file to the server" by server I meant TFS sserver. When you are mentioning a folder location in terms of "$/DEV", you are talking in TFS server location terms. You can copy files to addtional location, but you need to specify the location in terms of the physical location on the server and not TFS server terms. Since both are going to the droplocation, you can manipulate the BuildDetail.DropLocation property and get there. 

DropLocation\..\Latest

XCOPY recognizes only physical file location so dont mention "$\Dev" etc there.

Comment: Ok but there is no "server" in this case. It's the hosted MS virtual Team Foundation Service. It's all hosted by Microsoft. Does it matter?

Comment: So what would I do? xcopy C:\a\Binaries\myfile.dll BiuldDetail.DropLocation\Latest /Y /R
???

Comment: Is "Drops\Latest" an actual physical location on the server? Or are you basing it off the droplocation of the current build which is running? 

if you are basing it off the droplocation of the current build, then use xcopy C:\a\Binaries\myfile.dll DropLocation\..\Latest

Comment: No, there is no server in this case. It's Microsoft's hosted Team Foundation Service. Drops\Latest is a directory in TFS. What the regular build does is it creates the files in C:\a\Binaries and then does a CopyDirectory from C:\a\Binaries\ to $\Drops\CurrentIteration. (this works fine).

I've tried doing an additional CopyDirectory from C:\a\Binaries to $\Drops\Latest --- this works for the first time but future iterations do not copy. I still get the first copies of the DLLs, no updates.

Comment: You mean to say that during a regular build, the files from c:\a\binaires are checked back into the TFS directory Drops\CurrentIteration in TFS after each build????

Comment: I wouldn't say "checked back into" but rather copied into. The directory c:\a\binaries is a virtual directory on the TFS Hosted Machine. I do not have access to the server where this is done, it's hosted completely by Microsoft. Everything is cloud, no physical servers.

Comment: So in your build definition you have selected the option "copy build output to the following Source Control folder" right? Like this http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2012-oct-29.aspx 

My question: when you did the CopyDirectory from C:\a\Binaries to $\Drops\Latest, did it create a new folder under $\Drops\Latest or just put the files directly under the $\Drops\Latest folder?

Comment: Also try to use the DeleteDirectory activity and then delete your existing "$\Drops\Latest" folder before you do the CopyDirectory from C:\a\Binaries to $\Drops\Latest. 

Clearly for TFS foundation service, the copy directory is not just doing the regular copy. Internally it is calling the check-in to checkin files back to TFS. So hopefully the delete and new copy directory should work. Check and let me know.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing copy build output to the following Source Control Folder. The copy puts the files directly under $\Drops\Latest, no subfolder created. I've tried doing deletedirectory (<mtbwa:DeleteDirectory Directory="[DestinationPath]" DisplayName="Deleting Destination Path" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,22" />) -- I have an argument called DestinationPath. It's not deleting the directory. Very frustrating!

Comment: You can try one thing, manually delete the $\drop\latest folder and then do a build. Is that copying the new dll's properly? If so the MS logic for checking-in files back to the source control folder doesnt handle the condition when files are already present in the folder thats why it is not over writing. 

Assuming that the user which runs the build service has access to your source control, you can write a custom activity and use the TF.exe check-in command to check-in the files that you need back to the TFS directory. 

Thats my last suggestion and, I am sorry I couldnt help more!

Comment: No, deleting the folder manuaully and trying the build doesn't work. Probably because this is a delete and not a destroy. In order to use any .EXE command I would need an InvokeProcess because this is all on the hosted server. If anything else comes to mind, let me know. Appreciate you trying to help, thank you!

Comment: Yes either use Invoke process or add your own custom activity to the build template and give tf.exe checkin a chance. My heart says it will work.

Comment: If the file already exists then checkout and then do check-in

Comment: ARRGGG! Nope, no luck...getting: File name: 'tf' ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified...... It's not recognizing the "tf" commands for some reason

Comment: Any idea how to contact someone directly at Microsoft? We're paying for this service, they "should" be ready to help!

Comment: Possible that the tf.exe location is not in the PATH variable on the server. Assuming the VS 2010 is installed on the server and  VS100COMNTOOLS  environment variable is set properly, you can try this (VS100COMNTOOLS)..\IDE\TF.exe. 

If your company is paying for the services, am sure they will have a customer care.

Comment: Don't seem to be able to access the VSTool, get: Exception Message: File not found: (VS100COMNTOOLS)..\IDE\TF.exe (type FileNotFoundException).....Not sure how hosted Team Foundation Service handles this.

Comment: ALright buddy, that's all I got. Unless I start using the TF Service I dont think I would have more suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, appreciate the effort!